# Example of a URI that isn't a URL?

Tags: url, uri, web-standards

It's been explained to me numerous times that all URLs are URIs but not all URIs are URLs.  Can anyone give an example of something that is a URI but is not a URL?

Comment: Excellent question. [RFC 3986, section 1.1.3.](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-1.1.3) gives a definition but it lacks examples..  (Just in case the link becomes stale: "_The
   term "Uniform Resource Locator" (URL) refers to the subset of URIs
   that, in addition to identifying a resource, provide a means of
   locating the resource by describing its primary access mechanism
   (e.g., its network "location")._"

Answer (score 26):

Example stolen from [here](http://www.pierobon.org/iis/url.htm) (where there is also a description of the differences):

```
URL     http://www.pierobon.org/iis/review1.htm
URN     www.pierobon.org/iis/review1.htm#one
URI     http://www.pierobon.org/iis/review1.htm.html#one
```

Comment: I feel like this is wrong.  Isn't the URI example here also a URL?  It certainly locates a resource as well as identifying it.

Comment: As far as I know all these examples are URI which are URL as well!

Comment: `www.pierobon.org/iis/review1.htm#one` is not a URN because it does not start with `urn:` and it is not designed to name a resource in a way that is persistent, even if structure of the files on the server change.

Comment: Classic SO: much reputation! upvote! The answer lacks any context or explanation, and the examples are not correct. It links to a site with similar problems

Answer (score 13):

`urn:isbn:0451450523`

Source: [Uniform Resource Name - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Name)

Comment: I don't think isbn is related to web-standards.

Answer (score 8):

> An example of a URI that is neither a URL nor a URN would be a data URI such as:
> `data:,Hello%20World`
> It is not a URL nor a URN because the URI contains the data. It neither names it, nor tells you how to locate it over the network.

Taken from here: [What is the difference between a URI and a URL?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/19101/what-is-the-difference-between-a-uri-and-a-url)

I believe the answer from TofuBeer (most voted so far) is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

> A Uniform Resource Name (URN) is a URI that identifies a resource by name in a particular namespace. A URN can be used to talk about a resource without implying its location or how to access it. For example, the URN `urn:isbn:0-395-36341-1` is a URI

From: Wikipedia: [Uniform Resource Identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier)

Answer (score 4):

XML Schemas are often identified with a URI and while they may be formatted similarly there is no guarantee that there is anything there because it is not a URL.

The ability to identify the correct XML schema is necessary if you must validate an XML file. A means of identification must be shared between the content and the schema authors before successful validation can mean anything useful. URIs fill this need as good as anything else. Keep in mind that the schema is not necessarily needed in order to make use of the XML file. Therefore it does not need to be universal locatable or available, it simply needs to be identifiable. The semantics of a URI avoid the implication that the resource must be located "here", as would be the case with a URL, and with good reason. Such a detail is irrelevant to the task of identification.

Schema publishers will often base the URI off of a URL which they own. I can imagine there are many reason for doing this, but for one, it helps avoid naming conflicts without an intermediary. When using such a convention it is hard to resist hosting the definition at the location the URI would point to if it where a URL. While by know means necessary, I believe doing so marks an appreciated effort, and is an example of good information architecture, but this fact remains unrelated to needs filled by a URI.

Answer (score 3):

To test the exception failing in my unit test (covering URI ←→ URL conversion in Java), I use the following examples:

- `"_ "` — Non-valid `URI` from `String`
- `"data://valid-uri"` — valid `URI`, but not valid, malformed `URL` (`MalformedURLException` thrown from `URI#toURL`).
- `"valid-uri"` — valid `URI`, but not valid, non-absolute `URL` (`IllegalArgumentException` thrown from `URI#toURL`).
- `"http://   _"` — valid `URL`, but not valid, malformed `URI` (`URISyntaxException` thrown from `URL#toURI`).

It may be not an RFC-spec-perfect answer, but these are working examples for Java.

Answer (score 1):

A common case would be a [URN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Name), which is a URI of the format `urn:namespace-id:resource-id`.  Per Wikipedia:

> Defined in 1997 in RFC 2141, URNs were intended to serve as
>   persistent, location-independent identifiers, allowing the simple
>   mapping of namespaces into a single URN namespace.  The existence of
>   such a URI does not imply availability of the identified resource, but
>   such URIs are required to remain globally unique and persistent, even
>   when the resource ceases to exist or becomes unavailable.

Both styles of resource reference (URL and URN) were later combined under the  concept of the [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier), but they remain recognized as serving distinct purposes (emphasis mine):

> A Uniform Resource Name (URN) can be compared to a person's name,
>   while a Uniform Resource Locator (URL) can be compared to their street
>   address. In other words, a **URN identifies** an item and a **URL provides a
>   method for finding** it.